# Are my tables correct?

Tags: sql, database, vb.net

[image: Is this right?]

Anyway.  Here's the database design I made.  **tblGets** is my bridge entity between **tblStudent** and **tblOffense** though I am not quite sure with my table as of now seeing that it's not in its Third Normal Form (3NF).  I can't shake the feeling that my *Adviser* attribute is dependent upon the Section attribute and the *Section* attribute is dependent upon Student_ID.  So is it best to split the Adviser attribute as an attribute in another table thus creating another many-to-many relationship therefore producing another bridge entity?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To truly normalize the data you could add tables for

1) Section (assuming this is some organizational construct for students)

and

2) Advisor.

The foreign keys for Section and Advisor tables are input in the student table.  Section and Advisor tables then get their own ID fields plus section/advisor name.

I imagine Student - Advisor would be many-to-one (many students to one advisor) and section would be many-to-many.